# problema con yargs mensaje de error de sistaxis SyntaxError: Identifier 'argv' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un problema con yargs, que me da un error. Este es mi código:

Este es mi archivo app.js

```
const { argv } = require('node:process');
const { number, option } = require('yargs');
const { crearArchivo } = require('./helpers/multiplicar');
const argv = require('yargs');
    .option('e', {
        alias: 'element',
        type: 'number',
    })
    .argv;

console.clear();
console.log('element: yargs', argv.e);
```

Y el error es:

```
D:\git\proyectos\proyectos web\node\03-bases-node\app.js:5
const argv = require('yargs');
      ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'argv' has already been declared
```

Comment: Bienvenido Cristobal!. Recuerda que los logs de consola y el codigo va en texto, asi: `console.log('hello')`, no olvides leer: [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en la primera linea estas destructurando una propiedad llamada argv, mientras que en la linea de yargs declaras otra variable con el mismo nombre. Para solucionar el error debes ponerle otro nombre:

```javascript
const { argv:nodeArgs } = require('node:process');
console.log(nodeArgs); // nodeArgs es el nuevo nombre de la variable
```

Recuerda que la diferencia entre `let`, `var` y `const` es que `const` es un valor inmutable almacenado en memoria, `let` es un valor mutable almacenado en memoria pero con una accesibilidad mas restringida que `var`, mientras que `var` al contrario de `let` tiene una accesibilidad menos restringida.

Comment: Creo que deberías explicar que las variables ```const``` no pueden cambiar su valor lo que no pasa con ```let``` o ```var```

Comment: el problema esta en la linea 1 esta destructurando una variable con el nombre `argv`, pero en la linea 5 tambien esta declarando una variable `argv`, el error esta sucediendo por que las variables se llaman igual, cosa que tambien sucederia con let y var, la diferencia entre `let`, `var` y `const` es que `const` no cambia, `let` tiene un rango de accesibilidad mas corto que `var`, y `var` es mas accesible

Comment: Exacto, podrías agregar esa explicación a tu respuesta?

Comment: toda la razon esa linea la agrego vscode automaticamente muchas grascias